# Backbone .toJSON and .isNew in console no working

Tags: backbone.js

I am having trouble with some really basic Backbone.js functionality.

```
window.Album = new Backbone.Model.extend({});
album = Album({title:'OK Computer', artist:'Radiohead'});
album.isNew

    function () {
      return this.id == null;
    }

album.toJSON

    function () {
      return _.clone(this.attributes);
    }
```

.isNew, for instance, should just return 'yes'.

I'm using a gem "backbone-on-rails" if that makes any difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No man you don't have trouble with backbone, you have trouble with javascript ;)
In js, you need to call functions, i.e.

```
album.isNew();
album.toJSON();
```